# What is the correct way to associate objects with ApplicationUsers in Identity framework?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, webforms, asp.net-identity

Let's say that I am writing an API for a dating site. A member, or `ApplicationUser` must have a gallery of images to display on their profile. If I am storing the *URI* of the images in a database table called `MediaResource`, what is the correct way to link these images to the `ApplicationUser` in the database?

If each user must have one main profile photo, would a good solution be to add

```
public virtual MediaResource ProfilePhoto {get; set;}
```

to the `ApplicationUser` class?

> Is it as simple as adding
>
> ```
> public virtual ApplicationUser ResourceOwner {get; set;}
> ```
>
> to the `MediaResource` entity so that the
>   user will be stored as the foreign key in the database? Wouldn't this
>   approach scale poorly because I would have to find all of the user's
>   images in the database every time?

Answer (score 0):

My personal approach to your issue would be the following for his gallery. As you would retrieve all his pictures and select the profile out of these do it according following code:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
{
    ... { get; set; }

    // Schedule
    public virtual ICollection<MediaResource> WorkingHours { get; set; }

}
```

If you need to show the Profile picture without lazy loading all the other pictures, add a seperate property for his profile picture. Else create a boolean property on MediaResource to let you know that picture is his profile picture.

**Profile Picture on ApplicationUser**

```
public virtual MediaResource ProfilePicture{ get; set; }
```

**Profile Picture within MediaResource**

```
public class
{
    ...

    public bool IsProfilePictures { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You see, the thing that I'm worried about is having to deal with the possibility of multiple true values for IsProfilePicture. Wouldn't that approach mean that I have to make sure that all others are set to false every time? What if I had a virtual ICollection of all of the profile photos as well as a virtual MediaResource for the profile photo?

Comment: Personally I would feel myself most comfortable with "Profile Picture on ApplicationUser". This way you can change, remove, add, with the assurance to always only have 1 profile picture.

Comment: The "Profile Picture within MediaResource depends on building some more safety in your code, to only have 1 with the bool to true.